# How to use bluetooth with xcode OS X application simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, bluetooth

I have built a program using xcode for OS X. I need it to send characters over bluetooth to a development board. My question is can I use the internal bluetooth of my MBP to send those characters with the xcode simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: When you run an OSX app from xcode, it doesn't use the simulator but launch a real OSX app.

You can find a lot of sample code on github https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=bluetooth+peripheral&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 0):

No, in order to use Bluetooth you'll need to have an actual device.  The simulator won't work for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First, XCode simulator is used for iOS, not OS X. So I think your problem should be "How can I  build OS X App using bluetooth?".

There is a way to build bluetooth App on OS X, read:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Intro/BT_Intro.html

Comment: Thanks! When I press "run" in the XCode program I get a simulator, similar to the iOS simulator however it's for the OS X program I just created. I was wondering if from that simulator I press one of the buttons I created, can I utilize the bluetooth on my MBP to send the character?

Comment: What kind of XCode project have you created? Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to do that. I've put it on my google drive and here's the link.https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxyjKhqUMNKgTGpVODVJN1RYbUU/edit?usp=sharing

Basically what I need it to do is send A,B,C,D for the different buttons to the dev board and when the board sees a certain letter it will initialize a function.

Comment: That's not a "simulator" but your running program. Just follow the document to implement it, no one can help you write your own code.

Comment: That's my question. I need help with sending a character over bluetooth.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH216-TP9 Just read the document and try it yourself, if you meet problem then ask again, don't just expect others give you the code.